# How to get CloudFormation to respect Kinesis simultaneous stream creation limits

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation stack that contains multiple Kinesis streams.  If the stream count is less than 5 during creation or update, no problems.  If I have more than 5 an error occurs and the whole stack is rolled back.

The issue is compounded by streams in the template being added dynamically from config files, so order is not deterministic.

Is there a way to use wait conditions to say only do 5 of these at a time? Even this I think will be an issue because I won't know of streams that are being deleted.

OR is there some way to have CloudFormation back off a creation attempt, wait and try again without ROLLBACK on the whole stack?

Answer (score 0):

WaitConditions aren't really designed for this.  They are more for setting up servers that can ping when they're done.

There is no creation strategy for streams at this time.

According to the AWS response in this [thread](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/2512) the only way is to build up a dependsOn chain.  They suggest batching but I had to do a linked list since I wouldn't know what other stacks are up to.  Still not full proof but won't have more than 5 stacks building at once.